# Should sequence nature of input data within a mini-batch be maintained?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, data-science, lstm, mini-batch

Suppose a multivariate time series prediction problem for the following data

```py
rows = 2000
cols = 6
data = np.arange(int(rows*cols)).reshape(-1,rows).transpose()
print(data[0:20])  
print('\n {} \n'.format(data.shape))
print(data[-20:])
```

which prints out following data

```py
[[    0  2000  4000  6000  8000 10000]
 [    1  2001  4001  6001  8001 10001]
 [    2  2002  4002  6002  8002 10002]
 [    3  2003  4003  6003  8003 10003]
 [    4  2004  4004  6004  8004 10004]
 [    5  2005  4005  6005  8005 10005]
 [    6  2006  4006  6006  8006 10006]
 [    7  2007  4007  6007  8007 10007]
 [    8  2008  4008  6008  8008 10008]
 [    9  2009  4009  6009  8009 10009]
 [   10  2010  4010  6010  8010 10010]
 [   11  2011  4011  6011  8011 10011]
 [   12  2012  4012  6012  8012 10012]
 [   13  2013  4013  6013  8013 10013]
 [   14  2014  4014  6014  8014 10014]
 [   15  2015  4015  6015  8015 10015]
 [   16  2016  4016  6016  8016 10016]
 [   17  2017  4017  6017  8017 10017]
 [   18  2018  4018  6018  8018 10018]
 [   19  2019  4019  6019  8019 10019]]

 (2000, 6) 

[[ 1980  3980  5980  7980  9980 11980]
 [ 1981  3981  5981  7981  9981 11981]
 [ 1982  3982  5982  7982  9982 11982]
 [ 1983  3983  5983  7983  9983 11983]
 [ 1984  3984  5984  7984  9984 11984]
 [ 1985  3985  5985  7985  9985 11985]
 [ 1986  3986  5986  7986  9986 11986]
 [ 1987  3987  5987  7987  9987 11987]
 [ 1988  3988  5988  7988  9988 11988]
 [ 1989  3989  5989  7989  9989 11989]
 [ 1990  3990  5990  7990  9990 11990]
 [ 1991  3991  5991  7991  9991 11991]
 [ 1992  3992  5992  7992  9992 11992]
 [ 1993  3993  5993  7993  9993 11993]
 [ 1994  3994  5994  7994  9994 11994]
 [ 1995  3995  5995  7995  9995 11995]
 [ 1996  3996  5996  7996  9996 11996]
 [ 1997  3997  5997  7997  9997 11997]
 [ 1998  3998  5998  7998  9998 11998]
 [ 1999  3999  5999  7999  9999 11999]]
```

Consider the last column is the target time series to be predicted. If the batch-size is 20, Can I randomly skip some points e.g. 1009, 1012, 1015 from the first batch during training?
If yes, this mean we can randomly choose points within a time series to be used as training and test?